# Is it mandatory to call parent::__construct from the constructor of child class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, constructor

Is it mandatory to call the parent's constructor from the constructor in the child class constructor?

To explain consider the following example:

```
class Parent{

    function __construct(){
        //something is done here.
    }

}

class Child extends Parent{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //do something here.
    }

}
```

This is quite normal to do it as above. But consider the following constructors of the class `Child` :

```
function __construct(){
    //Do something here
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Is the above code correct? Can we do something before you call the parent's constructor? Also if we do not call the parent's constructor in the child's constructor like below is it legal?

```
class Child extends Parent{

    function __construct(){
        //do something here.
    }

}
```

I am from JAVA, and the types of constructor I have shown are not possible in Java. But can these be done in PHP?

Comment: No, you do not have to call the parent constructor, and yes, you may call the parent constructor after doing stuff in the child constructor.

Comment: If you don't extend ("call") the parent constructor you just overwrite it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it mandatory?

No

> Is the above code correct?

Yes

> Can we do something before you call the parent's constructor?

Yes. You can do it in any order you please.

> Also if we do not call the parent's constructor in the child's constructor like below is it legal?

Yes. But it's not **implicit** either. If the child constructor doesn't call the parent constructor then it will never be called because the child constructor overrides the parent. If your child has no constructor then the parent constructor will be used

Comment: Great, just adding this reference http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php and highlighting this note "Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared as private)."

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not mandatory to call the parent constructor, but if the parent constructor has side-effects that the child class should also have then it would be good. See [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/adn1-abf5) where one sub-class calls the parent constructor but the other doesn't. So it is still *valid* code if the parent constructor is not called.

Also, if the constructor is not declared in the subclass (which would override the parent constructor), then the constructor from the parent class will be utilized.