# Call to a parent class member from child without calling constructor dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, oop

I have my base controller and my content controller extending it like below, and I'm getting a `Call to a member function error() on null` so my question is:

Do I have to call the parent constructor?

If "yes" then is it better to have a service because the parent controller has some injected dependencies that I don't want to inject myself by calling the parent constructor

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class BaseController extends AbstractController
{
    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    protected $logger;

    
    /**
     * BaseController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}


class ContentController extends BaseController
{

private $contentRepository;
private $breadcrumbService;

public function __construct(
    ContentRepository $contentRepository,
    BreadcrumbInterface $breadcrumbService
) {
    $this->contentRepository = $contentRepository;
    $this->breadcrumbService = $breadcrumbService;
}

public function contentPage(...)
{
    try {
      ....
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
        $this->logger->error(...);
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you have a constructor in the child class, then you need to call `parent::__construct()`.

Comment: There are a few things around maybe worth a read - [Is it mandatory to call parent::__construct from the constructor of child class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244181/is-it-mandatory-to-call-parent-construct-from-the-constructor-of-child-class) and [Must I call parent::__construct() in the first line of the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748226/must-i-call-parent-construct-in-the-first-line-of-the-constructor)

Comment: Assuming that AbstractController is the Symfony framework AbstractController then be aware that it is a bit unusual in that a service locator (basically the container) is injected via setController.  That is how the abstract controller gets all of it's services without messing with the constructor.  If the main reason you want a BaseController is for the logger service then adjust the BaseController::getSubscribedServices method to add it.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#including-services

Answer (score 2):

You do not *need* to call the constructor. But you do need to set the `$logger` property if you want to use it.

```
class ContentController extends BaseController
{

    private $contentRepository;
    private $breadcrumbService;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ContentRepository $contentRepository,
        BreadcrumbInterface $breadcrumbService
    ) {
        $this->contentRepository = $contentRepository;
        $this->breadcrumbService = $breadcrumbService;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

}
```

With the above you no longer need to call `parent::__construct()`. But it's simply good practice, painless and harmless:

Just do:

```
public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ContentRepository $contentRepository,
        BreadcrumbInterface $breadcrumbService
) {
    $this->contentRepository = $contentRepository;
    $this->breadcrumbService = $breadcrumbService;
    parent::__construct($logger);
}
```

But if the only purpose of `BaseController` is to provide some logging methods, it's probably better to simply inject the logger service in `ContentController` and use it directly.